# Как создать постоянную переменную?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Мне бы хотелось создать собственный *.bat файл, в одной из частей которого пользователь сможет ввести собственное расположение папки, например, Steam. 
Смысл в том, чтобы затем использовать это расположение для команды `start steam.exe`. Примерно всё это без мусора выглядит так:

```
:1
@ECHO off
echo To proceed type 1. To set Steam dir type 2.
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==1 goto 2
if %cho%==2 goto 3
:3
SET /P steamdir=[Type your Steam dir here]
goto 1
:2
cd /D "%steamdir%"
start Steam.exe
goto 1
```

Вопрос вот в чем: *можно ли закрепить значение* `%steamdir%` так, чтобы при запуске этого же *.bat файла его не приходилось задавать раз за разом вручную?

К примеру сделать это так, чтобы пользователь, запустивший *.bat файл впервые и увидевший предложение указать директорию папки, совершил это действо, а затем при каждом запуске этого батника имел бы право всегда нажимать "1" и не париться о том, что ему нужно установить правильную директорию папки вместо директории той, откуда этот файл запускается.

И нет, я не хочу решать эту проблему простым переносом *.bat файла непосредственно в директорию Steam. Хочется мне научиться делать подобное, извините.

В оправдание своё могу сказать, что баловаться кодом начал совсем недавно и что мне очень бы хотелось всему научиться самому. Поэтому я прошу вас помочь. Спасибо.

*UPD1*: Поскольку в комментариях подсказали, как я могу достичь этого результата с помощью редактирования реестра, поспешу задать еще один вопрос. Используя:

```
SET /P steamdir=[Type your Steam dir here]
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Steamthing /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%steamdir%"
```

я смог записать значение `%steamdir%` в реестр, но, повозившись в батче некоторое время, готов сказать, что не приложу ума, как мне считать теперь это значение. Кто-нибудь поможет?

*UPD2*: Комментарии вновь помогли, что доказывает, например, группа из команд:

```
SET /P steamdir=[Type your Steam dir here]
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Steamthing /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%steamdir%"
echo %steamdir%
```

Благодарю всех за участие. Было очень познавательно узнать что-то от бывалых пользователей.

Comment: Можете записать в реестр или в файл и при следующем запуске взять от туда. Например: https://superuser.com/questions/761008/add-registry-key-entries-using-batch-file  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script

Comment: Здравствуйте, @Mike! Спасибо за столь быстрый и информативный ответ. Пишу, чтобы сказать: я сделал, что хотел — записал значение в реестр! Осталось только понять, как его оттуда считать... х) Использовал вот это:

`SET /P steamdir=[Type your Steam dir here] |
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Steamthing /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%steamdir%"`

Спасибо за какую бы то ни было кооперацию! Тем не менее, с нетерпением жду от вас ответа.

Comment: @Miri, никак не нужно считывать, просто значение будет перманентно записано в переменные окружения. Просто используете имя %steamdir% в своем скрипте никак его заранее не инициализируя, и все.

Comment: @insolor, черт подери, точно ведь! Все было так близко, а я и не заметил. Спасибо за терпение и участие!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите научиться сами это делать, то могу подсказать в какую сторону копать. А именно, пробуйте сохранить то что введено в файл, например, `./settings/steamPath.ini`. А уже когда запускается скрипт - проверять, есть ли такой файл. Если нету - просить ввести путь, а если есть - предлагать взять путь из этого файла. Ну и читать этот файл, собственно.

Ну а если этого будет недостаточно и нужно, чтобы все настройки были в одном файле, то можно попытаться прикрутить работу с ini-файлом, чтобы все настройки были в одном файле. Но для этого уже куда больше телодвижений придется совершить. В любом случае, начать стоит с "одна настройка - один файл".